# Define namespace::int class

Tags: c++, oop, namespaces

I kinda hoped that use of namespace will allow me do define classes with names of already existing classes - so the namespace will be the way to distinguish them.
I seek this because I have server protocol having some data types so I need classes that implement them, and their conversion to bytes.
This is what I did, and it produced errors:

```
#ifndef _PACKET_DATA_TYPES
#define _PACKET_DATA_TYPES
namespace mcp_t {
    class mcp_t::int {  //ERROR: expected an identifier

    }
}
#endif
```

If this is not possible, namespace seems a bit useless here - I'll be forced to use `mcp_int` instead anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` is a keyword, and keywords cannot be used to name user-defined types (even inside namespaces).

I am afraid you'll have to call your type something other than `int`.

Comment: This does not apply to normal classes (`std::string`), does it?

Comment: @TomášZato: Neither `std` nor `string` is a keyword. They are just identifiers like any other.

Answer (score 3):

You should not fully qualify the name of the class when providing its definition, and you should not use keywords as class names:

```
namespace mcp_t {
    class my_int {
        // ...
    };
}

mcp_t::my_int x;
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  `int` is a keyword and can't be used as an identifier in C++

Comment: because `int` is stil a keyword, even in namespace, I thought using `namespace::int` will be suitable workaround.